# How can I call a controller from other folder with ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 controllers in different folders. /Areas/Admin/Controllers/ and the other one is in /Controllers.

Here's the code I'm using
`@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Directory", "DirectoryWebService", new { ReturnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl }, new { @class = "common-button" })`

Using the code from Views/Directories/filename.cshtml works fine and generates the correct link "/DirectoryWebService/Directory?returnUrl=/Default/Traceability"
DirectoryWebService is in /Controllers folder

However, using this code from /Areas/Admin/Views/Organizations/Index.cshtml generates the following link "/**Admin**/DirectoryWebService/Directory
ReturnUrl=%2FDirectoryWebService%2FDirectory%3FreturnUrl%3D%2FDefault%2FTraceability"
Controller for Index.cshtml is in /Areas/Admin/Controllers/ folder

The question is how can I avoid /admin in the path for the second case? I haven't mentioned in my code.
PS I know about the a tag solution. It works fine but I need actionLink here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove the `area` variable from route.

```cs
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Directory", "DirectoryWebService", new {
  area = "",
  returnUrl = Model.ReturnUrl
}, new {
  @class = "common-button"
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like a charm. But why it works with "area"? I have "areas" folder not "area". I tried to add areas = "" but it doesn't work. Only area = "" as you advised.

Comment: @Stan `area` (not `areas`) is a route variable that defines the area where MVC Framework will look for the controller you want. By default it is the current requested area, but you can change it as I have shown.